# Youtube API search not returning live streams

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am using the Youtube API search command with type=video and eventType=live to ping Youtube periodically and automatically start a YT.player if a live video is detected.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&eventType=live&type=video&key={API_KEY}
```

BUT... sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes, though the Youtube channel page shows the live video, the API search just returns no items. While it isn't working, if I search for completed broadcasts then they are not up to date either. It's like the API is working from outdated status.

Is there a better way to detect a live stream?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're looking for [status.streamStatus](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#status.streamStatus). It has the value `active`, `created`, `error`, `inactive` and `ready`. Just use 'status' for the 'part' parameter and it should return the state of the stream.

Comment: Unfortunately status.streamStatus is only accessible by the authenticated stream originator, not the end user.

Comment: Indeed, it is meant for the authenticated user.

Comment: Hmm did not explain myself very well. The goal is to make an embedded Youtube player automatically switch to a live video stream if one is detected on a Youtube channel. Otherwise to play the most recent recorded video. This is for any website user, they will not be authenticated.

Comment: I wish you all the best.

Answer (score 0):

it's easy 
there is a parameter in *items* array under *snippet* which is *liveBroadcastContent*
it can be none or live try to filter it